# Is backpropogation used in convolutional neural networks?

Tags: cnn, backpropagation

Do convolutional neural network use the backpropogation algorithm? I am not understanding what exactly happens in fully connected layers?

Comment: But CNN comes under Feedforwad NN. And feedforward NN does not use backproppgation. right?

Answer (score 2):

Both Fully Connected Neural Networks and Convolutional Neural Networks use backpropagation for training.

What you said is right, both are feed forward neural networks, which means that the connections in the neural network start from left (input) and move towards right (output). But, it is feed forward only during inference time. During training i.e. when you are trying to find the weights/bias of the neural network for the task at hand, you have to use backpropagation.

Training has both forward pass and backward pass.
Inference has only forward pass.

Also, when we say feed forward it means that there are no loops in the network. L1->L2->L3->L4 and so on. But, if you see recurrent nets, they have loops like L->L->L->L

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking yes. I have not heard from anyone using a different algorithm. The math is the same as in fully connected layers. Only the architecture of the neural network is different.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, backpropagation is always used for optimization. The algorithm needs to adjust the weights and biases to minimize the cost function. But in computer codes, one doesn't have to do this explicitly. Packages like tensorflow have inbuilt functions for optimization.

The convolution layers exist to make sense of the image 'structure'. But after a few such layers, the required features are extracted, and a fully connected layer is used. The fully connected layers are like normal neural network layers (not CNN), where every node can influence every node of the next layer.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, for fine tunning of  parameters/weights we must need an optimizer. An optimizer is used back-propagation technique for optimising the cost by adjusting the param-weights(also known as coefficients).

> Some algorithms like Decision Tree, KNN doesn't work on the principal
>   of weights tunning and such type of algorithm doesn't required
>   optimizer.